# new to as3.. class structure and sprite

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to as3 and I'm trying to write a class that has to draw something.. I can't quite figure out how you put up the code?

player/Player.as:

```
package player {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Player extends Sprite {
        public var loader = null;

        public function Player(){
            this.cnstr_loader();
        }

        private function cnstr_loader(){
            this.loader = new Sprite();
            addChild(this.loader);
            this.loader.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
            this.loader.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
            this.loader.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
            this.loader.graphics.endFill();
            this.loader.x = 10;
            this.loader.y = 10;
            trace('e');
        }
    }
}
```

main.as:

```
import player.Player;
var _Player = new Player();
```

how can you draw the whole Player class in its own movieclip or sprite or what its called?

Comment: as @maxmc mentions, don't forget to add _Player to the display list too: addChild(_Player);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addChild` is what you are looking for. You should also read about the [DisplayList](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=2)